# when will vuetify 3.0 beta support v-data-table

Tags: v-data-table, vuetifyjs3

When is vuetify 3 going to support v-data-table in vue3?

i have tried to us vuetify 3.0 beta and apparently it doesn't support v-data-table with vue 3.
Is there a schedule for this? I'm stuck with the migrations as my apps uses this table as a main feature in the main page.

Answer (score 5):

According to this [comment on Github](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/13479#issuecomment-1115233462), data table will not be part of vuetify 3.0 but 3.1.

Comment: and that will come maybe in 2 years :D the whole situation with vuetify's update to Vue 3 is a mess. Lots of people have dropped vuetify from their projects because it was faster to switch than to wait for them to finally come up with anything usable

Comment: What would be a recommended Vue3 framework to ann app which deals with a lot of tables? Do you think is it worth to downgrade to Vue2 and then use Vuetify?

Comment: I would give primevue a look.

Answer (score 1):

It is available as part of [Vuetify Labs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/labs/introduction/#vuetify-labs) which contains components being worked on. You can import it separately as per the example and works relatively well already if your table is not too complex

Answer (score 0):

Vuetify 3.0 v-data-table headers JSON syntax has changed from

[{text: "column 1", value:" Column_1"}, ...]
to
[{title: "column 1", key:" Column_1"}, ...]

So, change the headers to the correct syntax, the data table should show up.